# how to run make command in bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04

I am writing a bash script to automate the installation. I am following steps from a guide. Below are the installation steps I need to write in script.

```
./configure
 make
 make all
```

I wrote my script like below.

```
function install_plugin {
          cd $INSTALLATION_FOLDER/some-plugins
          exec ./configure
          make
          make install
       }
```

The script works till ./configure and stops.

Comment: `configure` should not need `exec`, calling `./configure` should be fine. To use `make`, `make` must be in your `PATH` (it should be), but if not, then you will need to use the full path (e.g. `type -p make`)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I re-run the script and it is working fine :). But your suggestion for removing exec is helpful.